# Redirection using A record from .com.to .com.au

Tags: redirection

I have a client who has a .com site and a .com.au site. I host the .com.au site and for reasons that I cannot control she has another company managing the .com and her mail which goes to the .com.address The other company has set an A record to my server IP address to redirect the .com site, and I am struggling to figure out how to get the .com.to redirect to the .com.au where her website actually lives. At the moment I have set up the .com site on my server (which is hosted offsite, so I am managing this through WHM) and I have used the DNS of the other company to set this up.

This is where my knowledge starts to get a bit thin. How do I get my server to accept the redirected traffic from the other DNS? All I seem to get is the default web page site with the orange header which means its all messed up somewhere... Any advice?

Comment: What webserver are you using?

Comment: I am using WHM 11.36.1, I dont have access to Apache...as far as I know...

Comment: Well then talk to the sysadmin on this server so he can get you access. WHM and all other GUI control panels are *only* counter productive, as you're finding out.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Apache, just set up a simple redirection:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com
        redirect permanent / http://example.com.au/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I think it's the other way around; your .au should be on the Redirect, not the ServerName

Comment: @fukawi2 - you're right. Fixed. Good catch. For future reference you can just edit the answer and fix it yourself...

Comment: Yeah I know, but I wasn't 100% sure that I was right ;)

Comment: @fukawi2 - fair enough. Thanks again!